# robot_localization NaN output

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
When I execute the robot_localization with the differential mode for odometry data, I received nan value in the /odometry/filtered topic. When I turn on debug mode, I see the following texts. Could you please guide me how to start debugging?

Previous message time was 1507875840.235904932, current message time is 1507875840.269231081, delta is 0.03332614898681640625, velocity is (vX, vY, vZ): (0, 0, 0)
(vRoll, vPitch, vYaw): (0, -0, 0)
Previous measurement covariance:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Transformed covariance is
[-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan
-nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        -nan        ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273099/robot_localization-nan-output/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect your very high measurement variances are causing singularities in the Kalman filter. Make sure the input covariances are reasonable (see http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-11-09**:
Hi Ed Venator,
Thanks a lot for your answer. I changed the variances and it works.